# SoapClient save request to file instead of sending it

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, soap-client

Is there a way to save the soap request SoapClient sends when calling __soapCall to a file instead of sending it to the actual server?

I'm trying to save the soap requests to a queue and then send them over a period of time (the requests will be very different).

I'm using Zend_Soap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Zend_Soap_Client_Local, especially the _doRequest() method and build your own class with your own logic.

If you want so see how they used Zend_Soap_Client_Local, take a look in tests/Zend/Soap/ClientTest.php, method testGetFunctions().